# To merge n number of arrays into one using functions and pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

i have tried doing it with functions and arrays but have failed in-order to do it with pointers.
I want to do it with the help of pointers instead of arrays, but i am having problem with passing and calling the values of arrays using pointers.
below is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void final_array(int arr[], int size);
void array(int arr[], int i, int size);

int main()
{
int num, size[100];
int i, j;
int arr[100][100];

printf("Enter the number of arrays: \t");
scanf("%d", &num);
num = num < 100 ? num: 100;

//feeding elements.

for (i = 0; i<num; i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter the size of the array: \t");
    scanf("%d", &size[i]);

    printf("\nEnter the array: ");

    size[i] = size[i] < 100 ? size[i] : 100;
    array(&arr[i][0], i, size[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    final_array(&arr[i][0], size[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\nPress Enter key to exit.\n");
getchar();

 return 0;
}

void array(int arr[], int i, int size)
{
    int j;
for (j = 0; j<size; j++)
{
    printf("\nEnter arr[%d][%d]: \t",i, j);
    scanf("%d", &arr[j]);
}
}

void final_array(int arr[], int size)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", arr[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: *i have tried doing it with functions and arrays but have failed in-order to do it with pointers.* -Confusing to me

Comment: I didn't understand what you want to achieve?

Comment: probably he wants to add several arrays into program and write their values as one array

Comment: Please provide more explanation and details. Rephrasing your text for clarity might also be helpful. Please add examples of data to process and show some kind of desired result. As it is now, the question is unclear, even the existing answer starts off with "I guess...".

Answer (score 0):

I guess this should solve your problem.Let me know if it's correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void final_array(int *arr, int size);
void array(int *arr, int i, int size);

int main()
{
int num;

int i, j;
int **arr=(int **)malloc(100 * sizeof(int *));
for (i=0; i<100; i++)
        arr[i] = (int *)malloc(100 * sizeof(int));

printf("Enter the number of arrays: \t");
scanf("%d", &num);
int *size=malloc(sizeof(int)*num);
num = num < 100 ? num: 100;

//feeding elements.

for (i = 0; i<num; i++)
{
    printf("\nEnter the size of the array: \t");
    scanf("%d", &size[i]);

    printf("\nEnter the array: ");

    size[i] = size[i] < 100 ? size[i] : 100;
    array(&arr[i][0], i, size[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<num; i++)
{
    final_array(&arr[i][0], size[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

printf("\nPress Enter key to exit.\n");
getchar();

 return 0;
}

void array(int *arr, int i, int size)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j<size; j++)
    {
        printf("\nEnter arr[%d][%d]: \t",i, j);
        scanf("%d", &arr[j]);

    }
}

void final_array(int *arr, int size)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<size; j++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", arr[j]);
    }
}
```